# How could Aang stay alive for 100 years?

Tags: avatar

Is there any clear description as to how Aang survived for 100 years inside of the iceberg?

Can Avatars do that? If they can, then why didn't the other Avatars stay alive for long time periods? And whatever was the case, how did Aapa stay alive too?

Comment: The Avatar cant age all because he was in the Avatar state when he wrapped himself up with the iceberg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**Avatar Wiki**](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Aang):

> However, Aang later discovered that he would be sent to the Eastern Air Temple in order to complete his airbending training far away from Monk Gyatso, whom the other monks thought was too soft on him. Afraid and confused, the young airbender ran away with his flying bison, Appa, though they became caught in a storm shortly after, which caused them to crash into the water. Aang saved himself and Appa from drowning by semi-consciously entering the Avatar State and freezing them both in a sphere of ice through a combination of airbending and waterbending. The Avatar State kept him alive, albeit not fully conscious, in the iceberg for about a hundred years while the war raged on.

Comment: "The Avatar State kept him alive, albeit not fully conscious, in the iceberg for about a hundred years while the war raged on." is unsourced :(

Answer (score 6):

In the Avatar universe, much like in the *Futurama*, *Frozen* or *Once Upon a Time* universes, some people who are frozen under certain conditions have their metabolisms pause.

In *A:TLA*, Aang, after freezing himself and Appa, is sustained through the Avatar State according to this [currently unsourced portion of Aang's page in Avatar Wikia](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Aang):

> The Avatar State kept him alive, albeit not fully conscious, in the iceberg for about a hundred years while the war raged on.

I am guessing the Avatar State also sustains Appa.

This does not really happen in real life except for things like [Cryptobiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptobiosis) but is seen in much fantasy and scifi.

#### Further reading

- [Wikipedia - Suspended animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspended_animation)
- [TvTropes - Human Popsicle](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanPopsicle)
- [Zidbits - Can A Human Be Frozen And Brought Back To Life?](http://zidbits.com/2011/02/can-a-human-be-frozen-and-brought-back-to-life/)
- [Wikipedia - Cryonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics)